# Error - An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListBuckets operation:

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Error - An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListBuckets operation:

Steps

1. Configured AWS Cli on linux machine:

## aws configure -> Access Key, secrete key

## aws configure list

new access with secrete

2. Remove Access key & secrete key: Deleted Access key and secret key.
3. When try to see s3 suckets: (Assigned EC2 role to access S3 bucket)

aws s3 ls

Error - An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListBuckets operation:

Solution:

1. remove files config credentails from folder ~/.aws/

cd ~/.aws/

config credentails

2. stored profile as default -  cmd -  aws configure set StoreAs Default
3. #aws s3 ls
   you will get s3 bucket list, as per the role assigned to EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. remove files config credentails from folder ~/.aws/

cd ~/.aws/

config credentails

2. stored profile as default -  cmd -  aws configure set StoreAs Default
3. #aws s3 ls
   you will get s3 bucket list, as per the role assigned to EC2 instance.